# Emails for concurrent jenkins builds without waiting

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I am using Jenkins 1.495.

The problem is that when concurrent builds are enabled emails will not be sent until all the builds finish.

I have followed the issue and it stems from the fact that all builtin email notifications actions all have triggers which are dependent on previous builds so that they can know if the current build is 'still failing' or 'fixed' or 'broken' or 'still success' etc etc. This can be easily seen [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16376).

I want to know how to send emails without waiting for other builds, via:

- An existing plugin that can solve my problem.
- Write or adapt my own email plugin.
- A clever solution that I would never have thought of.

If I am to write or adapt my own email plugin, I would like to know if anyone has any experience with this, or a solution they might already have that they could share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided I should put an answer here (it's been a few years since the question was asked)

I solved this by simply writing the email report myself, and not using the built-in.

I know this doesn't solve the problem, but that's my workaround.

In fact, eventually we simply moved the entire process from Jenkins to our own scripts, and just used Jenkins as a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation.

I am thinking of using a trigger parameterized build to trigger a secondary job to send out the email.